# How can I use CSRF tokens provided by the play framework (play-2.2.3) with a PHP front-end?

Tags: java, php, playframework, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using play-2.2.3 to develop APIs. These APIs are accessed by a PHP/JQuery front-end. Simple example would be a resetPassword API. From the PHP, when I call the reset password API, it should be protected by a CSRF token so that someone cannot simply call that API and reset someone else's password. 
Short of rendering the form using Scala (provided by Play-2.2.3), is there a way to manually have single-use server-side tokens which appear as hidden form fields in the reset password form and get verified in the post request by the server on submit of the form?

Comment: Which part of your application set up creates the user session: PHP or Play? How is your Play API protected from direct access? Are there any configurations for Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) set up for your PHP and Play applications?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to do this.

1. On the play side, do NOT put any csrf settings in the application.conf
2. Use the `@AddCSRFToken` annotation on a method that will set a cookie called `PLAY_SESSION=.....-csrfToken=........`
3. In the API calls that need to be validated pass the `PLAY_SESSION` cookie entirely, AND in the queryString, pass the `csrfToken=.....`.